# Shortcuts don't work in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

I have English Windows 8, English Office 2013 and a few keyboard languages.

When I set the English keyboard and start Word, shortcuts work. But when I change the English keyboard to other languages and start Word, shortcuts don't work. I don't have this issue in Excel 2013.

Why might this be?

Comment: I would like to add some comments.
I've discovered, that this is really bug in office 2013, which is used on Windows with few languages. For example, if Word/Excel or any other Office 2013 program is started, when the current keyboard language is not english (Russian for example) the hotkeys will not work at all!! Crtl+A/V/C/X etc... hotkeys are disabled!!! But if you close document, switch your keyboard to English and open it again, the hotkeys will back working. This is really annoying bug, I was reporting it since release preview of office 2013, but it has been successfully moved to RTM off

Answer (score 2):

Try setting Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language\Advanced settings\"Let me set a different input method for each app window"

It's not a fix, more of a workaround, but helps.

Comment: This option doesn't exist in Windows 7 - [only in Windows 8](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rkKwO.png). At least I can't find such an option...

Answer (score 0):

Goto....
File...Options...Language
check if keyboard layout is written "enabled" or "not enable"
if "not enable", click on it and it opens Text Services and Input Laguage options.
add English US default keyboard.
Then select the 'English - US' as your default input language...apply and ok.
Restart word and all will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is **OneNote 2013 icon** in your notification area (tray bar).
Right click on it and **Quit**.

Restart Word 2013.

Now shortcuts should work.

Answer (score 0):

See file - options - language
under "Choose Display and help languages"
set both to english and click on set as default, then restart the office app